# Entity Framework: "The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable" when adding child objects

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I'm aware this question has been asked a few times on here already, and the common answer seems to be that this error arises when old child objects aren't deleted correctly when being modified or removed from their parent. However, I'm attempting to do neither of these things, and I'm still getting the error.

My system works roughly like this:

I have a pencil factory which makes pencils of many different varieties, and these are sold in sets. The pencil cases which these sets come in are also manufactured by me. Each individual pencil can be uniquely identified, as can the cases. Pencils cannot be sold or owned independently from their case, however if a new pencil is designed and added to an existing case, we send one of these pencils out to each customer who has already purchased that particular case.

So we have five tables here:

- PencilCase

  - id
  - style
- Pencil

  - id
  - colour
  - pencilCase
- CustomerPencilCase

  - serialNumber
  - pencilCase
  - customer
- CustomerPencil

  - serialNumber
  - pencil
  - customerPencilCase
- Customer

  - id
  - name

The following is a function used to create a new CustomerPencil, generate a unique serial number for it, and add it to the database. 'db.SaveChanges()' is called here in order to reduce the risk of collisions.

```
Private Function CreateNewCustomerPencil(pencil As Pencil, customerPencilCase As CustomerPencilCase) As CustomerPencil
    Dim customerPencil As New CustomerPencil
    Dim serialNumber As String

    Dim isUnique As Boolean = False
    While isUnique = False
        serialNumber = GenerateSerialNumber()
        If (From cp In db.CustomerPencils Where cp.serialNumber = serialNumber).Count < 1 Then
            isUnique = True
            customerPencil.serialNumber = serialNumber
            customerPencil.pencil = pencil
            customerPencilCase.customerPencils.Add(customerPencil)
            db.SaveChanges()
        End If
    End While

    Return customerPencil
End Function
```

So, as explained above, there are two cases where this function is called. The first is when a new Pencil is added to a PencilCase. In this instance, a CustomerPencil associated with the new Pencil is added to each CustomerPencilCase that corresponds to the PencilCase. **This subroutine works perfectly in conjunction with the above function**.

```
Private Sub AssignPencilToPencilCase(pencil As Pencil, pencilCase As PencilCase)
    Dim customerPencilCaseQuery = From cpc In db.CustomerPencilCases Where cpc.pencilCase.id = pencilCase.id Select cpc
    Dim customerPencilCases As List(Of CustomerPencilCase) = customerPencilCaseQuery.ToList

    For Each customerPencilCase As CustomerPencilCase In customerPencilCases
        Dim customerPencil = CreateNewCustomerPencil(pencil, customerPencilCase)
    Next
End Sub
```

The other case is when a Customer purchases a new CustomerPencilCase. In this instance, for each Pencil that exists in the corresponding PencilCase, a new CustomerPencil must be created. **This is the problematic subroutine, which fails when db.SaveChanges() is called in the above function**.

```
Private Sub AssignPencilCaseToCustomer(pencilCase As PencilCase, customerPencilCase As CustomerPencilCase)
    Dim pencils = GetPencils(pencilCase.id)

    For Each pencil As Pencil In pencils
        Dim customerPencil = CreateNewCustomerPencil(pencilCase, customerPencilCase)
    Next
End Sub
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a number of days now, and would be ever so grateful if anyone can suggest what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show an example `Pencil` object you pass into the `CreateNewCustomerPencil` function? EF has an ability to include the foreign key in the classes it generates for the entities.  Are you sure this is being populated?  If you set it to `0` you could break the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Phew, managed to fix it. Thank you very much, Justin, for your comment which nudged me in the right direction.

In this instance the problem lay in the `Pencil` object I was sending to the `CreateNewCustomerPencil` function. The one passed initially to `AssignPencilToPencilCase` was retrieved directly from the database earlier on and thus worked fine. However, the ones retrieved by `GetPencils` in the broken subroutine were actually altered slightly after retrieval. This caused EF to think that I'd modified those Pencils, meaning the existing Pencils in the database became orphaned, resulting in the non-nullable foreign key error.